# How to join an intermediate table with itself and add new empty columns to it?

Tags: sql, oracle

The database is oracle sql.

This is my table:

```
SELECT d.a
,d.b
,e.c
FROM d
    ,e
WHERE d.a > d.b
```

I want to add f, g and h columns.

I don't want it to create a new table in the database, just want to add columns to above intermediate table.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't *silly*, it is just difficult to understand what you are trying to do. An example (current table and desired result) would probably help.

Meanwhile, here's how I understood it: I've taken your query and modified it a little bit:

```
select d.a,
       d.b,
       e.c,
       -- the following columns might be what you are looking for
       null d,
       null e,
       null f
from d cross join e
where d.a > d.b;
```

Your query will do a Cartesian product of tables `d` and `e`; is it intentional? There's no join between them.

The above query applied to some sample data (so that you could be able to visualize what's going on); the result contains 3 new columns, `d`, `e` and `f` which don't have any value (as you wanted):

```
SQL> with
  2  d (a, b) as
  3    (select 100, 200 from dual union all
  4     select 300, 150 from dual union all
  5     select 400, 200 from dual
  6    ),
  7  e (c) as
  8    (select 'A' from dual union all
  9     select 'B' from dual
 10    )
 11  select d.a,
 12         d.b,
 13         e.c,
 14         -- the following columns might be what you are looking for
 15         null d,
 16         null e,
 17         null f
 18  from d cross join e
 19  where d.a > d.b;

         A          B C D E F
---------- ---------- - - - -
       300        150 A
       400        200 A
       300        150 B
       400        200 B

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DATA AS
  ( SELECT dummy,
           CAST(null AS number) AS NumberPlaceholder,
           CAST(null AS VARCHAR(255)) AS CharPlaceHolder
      FROM dual
  );
```

Comment: I do not want to create a new table. I want to modify my intermediate table.

Comment: Then you'd have to do "ALTER TABLE TEST_DATA 
  ADD NumberPlaceHolder Number"; This will just add a place holder column to your existing table. I don't really understand what you mean by "join to itself". If you want to alter the existing data you'll need to create a backup table as SELECT * FROM TEST_DATA, then drop TEST_DATA, and do the approach for adding columns that I suggested originally.

Comment: Thank you, I think I can get rid of join. 
But still in your approach you are creating new table in database which I want to avoid.

Imagine i have  below table:

select d.a, d.b, e.c
from d, e
where d.a>d.b

I want to add column f,g,h to above table.

And also I do not want to create one more table in database. This intermediate
table result will be copied into my python dataframe.

Comment: @Shailaja I've added this query to the question, written with good join syntax. I'm not sure what information it's meant to provide though. An "ALTER TABLE" command will add columns to an existing table.

Comment: I tried below query its not working. can you take a look?

with subq as (select d.a, d.b, e.c 
          from d, e 
          where d.a>d.b 
)
alter table  subq  add fcst1 int;

Comment: I am new to SQL, please pardon if I am asking very silly questions

Comment: @shailaja I think you might just be confusing terminology. Subq in your query is not a real table, it's a common table expression, pretty much only syntactically different than a subquery. So you cannot perform updates/deletes/inserts/alter/etc against it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the values you want:

```
SELECT d.a, d.b, e.c, 'f' as f, 'g' as g, 'h' as h
FROM . . .
```